# Hidding values of column with ****xy using python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am stuck in a coding problem, in Python, I have a CSV file having two columns Flag | Customer_name, I am using data frames so if flag is "0" I want to print complete name and if Flag=1 then I want to hide first n-2 alphabets of Customer name with "*" for example,

```
 if flag=1 then,
 display *********th (for john smith)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create the number of `'*'` needed and then add the last two letters:

```
name = 'john smith'
name_update = '*' * (len(name)-2) + name[-2:]
print(name_update)
```

output:

```
********th
```

Answer (score 0):

As you used `dataframe` as tag, I assume that you are working with `pandas.DataFrame` - in such case you might harness regular expression for that task.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john smith']})
df['redacted'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'.(?=..)', '*')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         name    redacted
0  john smith  ********th
```

Explanation: I used here positive lookahead (kind of zero-length assertion) and I replace any character with `*` if and only if two any characters follows - which is true for all but 2 last characters.

Comment: using this logic i have to implement a loop (iterate) for accessing each element of the column  .   also   quote --   "I replace any character with * if and only if two any characters follows - which is true for all but 2 last characters." in regex expression which term is used to restrict to only last two character  pls explain

Comment: @vikassingh how many last characters will be shown in this solution depend on lookahead content `(?=..)` means 2 characters, `(?=...)` means 3 characters, `(?=....)` means 4 characters and so on; Note that you might also use exact number of repetition for example `(?=.....)` is equivalent to `(?=.{5})`